# OnApplyTemplate in Windows Phone 8.1 Siverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I use templates to change the look of the default button in Visual Studio. I was drawing a polygon and use ContentPresenter tag to insert text in a polygon that

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="AnswerChoose" TargetType="Button">
        <Border BorderThickness="2">
            <Grid Name="ButtonAnswer">
                <Polygon Name="BorderAnswer" Points="0,50 30,20, 270,20 300,50 270,80 30,80" Stroke="White" StrokeLineJoin="Bevel" StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Polygon.Fill>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF0A080D" Offset="0.0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF15224C" Offset="0.2"/>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#FF0460C3"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF15224C" Offset="0.8"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF0A080D" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Polygon.Fill>
                </Polygon>
                <ContentPresenter Name="ContentAnswer" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

and here is my button:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Tap="ChangeColorButton_Tap">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Name="A" Content="A." Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource AnswerChoose}" />
            <Button Name="B" Content="B. " Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource AnswerChoose}"/>
            <Button Name="C" Content="C. " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource AnswerChoose}"/>
            <Button Name="D" Content="D. " Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource AnswerChoose}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Now, I want if I click on that button, it will change color, but I have a problem: if I click on the node and edge attributes OriginalSource returns the border and if I click on the text of the button, it returns TextBlock. How do I know whether my Visual Studio click anywhere on the button will return the "button". I have references on MSDN but it only vaguely OnApplyTemplate use. Can you tell me how to use it or offer other solutions are not?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add an event handler to every button, maybe you can try using `VisualTreeHelper` to search the elements.

Try this code in your `ChangeColorButton_Tap` event handler:

```
var pos = e.GetPosition(null);
var buttons = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(pos, LayoutRoot).Where(item => item is Button);
foreach (var uiElement in buttons)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(uiElement);
}
```